# how to allow programs to communicate through windows Firewall in C#

Tags: c#

I want to allow some program to communicate through the Windows Firewall use C# programming(Support Window 7).
But I can't.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html

Comment: Try opening Visual Studio first.

Comment: @ppp Why do you want c# to add an exception? You can do that manually, if you got enough rights though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interop to access the COM objects used to configure the firewall.

[Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To get access to the API using interop you need to create in interop assembly. You can use `tlbimp.exe` to do that.

1. Open a Visual Studio command prompt.
2. Change diretory into a suitable writable folder.
3. Execute the command `tlbimp FirewallApi.dll`.

The interop assembly is created in the file named `NetFwTypeLib.dll`. Add a reference to this file in your C# project.

To create an object you need to write code like this:

```
var firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2) Activator.CreateInstance(
  Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
```

You need to use the correct `ProgID` as specified in the documentation linked above and you then need to cast the returned object to the correct interface. From that point you can explore the API using IntelliSense.