# In vb.net is there a windows API that shows the same information as "Netsh AdvFirewall Firewall show"

Tags: vb.net, cmd, windows-firewall, netsh

So right now I am trying to see the information that comes out of the following command in to command prompt (cmd):

> netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="TestFirewallUpdateSettings"  profile=any

The output I get is:

```
 Rule Name:                            TestFirewallUpdateSettings

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Enabled:                                 Yes Direction:                  
 In Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
 Grouping: LocalIP:                              Any RemoteIP:         
 Any Protocol:                             Any Edge traversal:         
 No Action:                               Allow
```

What I want is to just read the In Profiles section using vb.net and wondering if there is a API that will do what I am asking for?

Comment: No, there is not direct API to do this, but it can be done very easily with a little bit of `Regex` and parsing... Please show us an attempt at what you have tried and where you are stuck and then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You could go and create your own interop assembly in order to access the objects - `INetFwPolicy2` in particular - in the system's COM based FirewallApi.dll. Check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139776/how-to-allow-programs-to-communicate-through-windows-firewall-in-c-sharp) for details. I did this in the past (Windows 7) and it worked like a charm.

Also, there is a WMI name space - ROOT\SecurityCenter2 - which is supposed to provide info about firewall amongst other things. However it wasn't well documented and I failed to enumerate it through C# although I can see it through various WMI browser tools.

You can also check the new [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.INetFwPolicy2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.inetfwpolicy2(v=vs.120).aspx). It seems to do the same job as the manually created interop assembly.